# how to pass a variable by ref reference in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a scope variable which has `false` value by default.

I want when I pass this variable to a function to modify it's value to `true`.

but this can't be done since the passage of params in JavaScript is by value.

this is a simple code of what I'm tryin to do:

```
myapp.controller('PersonCtrl', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.step = false;
    change($scope.step);
    console.log($scope.step);
});

change = function(step){
  step = true;
}
```

**jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/SNF9x/177/

how can I solve this ?

Comment: Why don't you declare a global variable?

Comment: pass the $scope instead of $scope.step if possible, else just set $scope.step to the return value of the function.

Comment: @HarishKumar In any non-trivial application, global variables quickly become cumbersome and prone to conflicts

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the object holding the primtive to your change function:

```
myapp.controller('PersonCtrl', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.step = false;
    change($scope);
    console.log($scope.step);
});

change = function(obj){
  obj.step = true;
}
```

You could event pass the name of the variable you want to change:

```
myapp.controller('PersonCtrl', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.step = false;
    change($scope, 'step');
    console.log($scope.step);
});

change = function(obj, prop){
  obj[prop] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass variables by reference in JS, but you can pass objects by reference and then modify the properties, like this...

```
myapp.controller('PersonCtrl', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.step = false;
    change($scope);
    console.log($scope.step);
});

change = function($scp){
  $scp.step = true;
}
```

**jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/SNF9x/178/

Comment: I would recommend against starting the parameter name with a `$`.

Comment: I would not, since the original variable uses a `$` prefix, but it's neither right nor wrong and just preference.

Comment: I'm thinking that it would cause confusion; generally (or at least in my experience) `$var` means it's global. If it isn't, in a larger method it may end up being confusing.

Comment: As I said, it's a preference.  I personally use `_` to prefix global variables, and `$` if it's a jQuery object.  In this question I simply left it with the prefix it already had.  This really isn't a point for discussion though, as it's nothing more than a choice.

Comment: Oh, I must have missed those last three words. Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

In your OP you try to change the value of a primitive type:

```
var o = {
  b: true
};
changeValue(o.b);//pass a primitive type to the function
console.log(o.b);//print out true because is primitive type and all primitive types pass by value

function changeValue(b) {
  b = false;
}
```

One solution will be to pass the object `$scope` to the function:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.controller('PersonCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.step = false;
  change($scope);
  console.log($scope.step);//prints out true
});

change = function(obj) {
  obj.step = true;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ko9bwtfp/)